# Powershell Popup Box not showing when installing through SCCM

Tags: powershell, sccm

Not sure how to fix it but I think i have a hunch on why
I have a powershell script installs an applications but before it kicks off it shows a msgbox that simply displays a message to the user

The script works perfectly when I run it manually and even running it as the System account through psexec works as well

However when deploying this through SCCM - Software center, it installs without displaying the msgbox..

Now I think it might be because its not showing in the context of the current logged in user.. but I would of thought running it through Psexec as system would not work either...

Can anyone help? I have deployed it as an application through sccm using this script:

```
<#
.Date: 01-Jun-2016
.Ansys 16.2 Install Script


# Set up some Variables
$workingDirectory = (split-path $myinvocation.mycommand.path -parent)

# Display a warning message before installation begins
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::MsgBox('Ansys 16.2 takes over 30 mins to install. Please do not log out or shutdown your computer during the installation. You can continue working as normal while it is being installed. Once complete you will see in Software Center say "installed" next to Ansys 16.2.', 'OKOnly,SystemModal,Exclamation', 'Warning')

# ***** Install Application ******
Start-Process -FilePath "$WorkingDirectory\ANSYS162_WINX64_Disk1\setup.exe" -ArgumentList "-silent -disablerss -licserverinfo `"::licensing-b`"" -Wait -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Start-Sleep -s 3

# ***** Delete Shortcut and unlicensed products *******
Remove-Item "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\ANSYS 16.2\Uninstall ANSYS 16.2.lnk" -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Remove-Item "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\ANSYS 16.2\ANSYS Icepak 16.2.lnk" -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Remove-Item "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\ANSYS 16.2\Aqwa" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Remove-Item "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\ANSYS 16.2\ACP" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Remove-Item "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\ANSYS 16.2\ANSYS Client Licensing" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue    "#>
```

Comment: In SCCM, what settings do you have configured for the Deployment Type > User Experience?

Comment: In User experience Tab:
Installation behaviour - install for system
Logon Requirement - Only when user is logged on
Installation visibility - Normal

Allow users to interact with program installation is checked

I have played around with all these settings and had no luck

I think its due to the pop up box being shown on the SYSTEM account instead of the currently logged in user

Is it possible in powershell to make the msgbox appear only in the currently logged on user context?

Comment: As it is impossible to have a really silent powershell script execution you should always at least for a split second see the powershell window popping up. Does this happen? Meaning: Is nothing of this setup visible for the user or just not the messagebox? To me it sounds like the msgbox fails rather than be displayed somewhere wrong because they way you programmed it the msgbox blocks until accepted so it would not even continue if it was displayed in the wrong user session imo.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have checked "allow the user to interact with this program" option while deployment

[click here to see how to set user interaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcqXp.jpg)